# Troubles with sssd and Active Directory Integration

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, kerberos, sssd

I have Debian Squeeze and sssd installed. When I try to login to server by user 'alexwinner' by ssh I see in the log:

```
(Fri May 11 18:56:03 2012) [[sssd[krb5_child[26281]]]] [get_and_save_tgt] (1): 523: [-1765328360][Preauthentication failed]
```

But when I execute `kinit alexwinner` all is ok, I receive ticket.
This is my sssd.conf

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
reconnection_retries = 3
sbus_timeout = 30
services = nss, pam

domains = MYDOMAIN.COM

[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root
reconnection_retries = 3

; entry_cache_timeout = 600
; entry_cache_nowait_timeout = 300

[pam]
reconnection_retries = 3


[domain/MYDOMAIN.COM]
description = LDAP domain with AD server
enumerate = true

min_id = 1000
cache_credentials = false

id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = krb5
chpass_provider = krb5

krb5_realm = MYDOMAIN.COM
krb5_kdcip = 172.27.250.141
krb5_kpasswd = 172.27.250.141
ldap_pwd_policy = none

ldap_id_use_start_tls = false
ldap_tls_reqcert = never

ldap_uri = ldap://172.27.250.141:3268/
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
ldap_default_bind_dn = ECAAuthUser@mydomain.com
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = veryhardpassword


ldap_user_search_base = ou=linux,ou=users,ou=pro,dc=mydomain,DC=com
ldap_user_object_class = user
ldap_user_uid_number = uidNumber
ldap_user_gid_number = GIDNumber
ldap_user_home_directory = unixHomeDirectory
ldap_user_shell = loginShell
ldap_user_principal = userPrincipalName
ldap_user_name = sAMAccountName
ldap_user_gecos = displayName
ldap_user_uuid = objectGUID

ldap_group_search_base = OU=Linux,OU=Roles,DC=mydomain,DC=com
ldap_group_object_class = group
ldap_group_name = Name
ldap_group_gid_number = GidNumber
ldap_force_upper_case_realm = True
```

and this is my krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MYDOMAIN.COM
    forwardable = true

[realms]
    MYDOMAIN.COM = {
        kdc = 172.27.250.141
        admin_server = 172.27.250.141
   }
```

I tried to see tcpdump for kerberos packages and see that padata is different for login and kinit.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Try below settings, They work pretty well in my environment.

Make changes to /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf  |grep -v ^# |grep -v ^$
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
reconnection_retries = 3
sbus_timeout = 30
services = nss, pam
domains = default
[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root
reconnection_retries = 3
[pam]
reconnection_retries = 3
[domain/default]
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
cache_credentials = True
ldap_group_object_class = group
ldap_search_base = dc=example,dc=com
chpass_provider = krb5
ldap_default_authtok = RedHat1!
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = krb5
ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com
ldap_user_gecos = displayName
debug_level = 0
ldap_uri = ldap://10.65.208.43/
krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
krb5_kpasswd = 10.65.208.43
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
ldap_force_upper_case_realm = True
ldap_user_object_class = person
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts
krb5_server = 10.65.208.43
```

1. Run the authconfig-tui tool. Select ldap under the "User Information" section and Kerberos under the "Authentication" Section.
2. On the ldap Settings step. Leave the use TLS option unselected put the AD servers fully qualified domain name in and the base DN.
3. On the kerberos Settings page enter the AD servers Realm, also list the AD servers  fully qualified domain name for the KDC and Admin Server.

This will result in restarting sssd daemon.

Verify :-

```
[root@localhost ~]# id user1
```

Make sure you have IDMU installed on your AD box & users have unix attributes set.